# MVVM and MAUI : How to get and refresh values from V in the VM?

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

I am (very) new to MAUI (and to MVVM) and my question might be childish, but I'm haven't found an answer yet. I have a MainViewModel which contains a method which essentially calls this:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(CarPage), true, new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {"Car", car}
    });
```

This opens my CarPage.

CarPage.xaml looks like this (snip):

```
        <Grid Padding="20" RowSpacing="20">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               ......

            <Label
                Grid.Row="3"
                Style="{StaticResource MediumLabelCentered}"
                Text="{Binding Car.Color, StringFormat='Color: {0}'}" />
```

Then I have this:

```
        <Picker
                x:Name="picker"
                Grid.Row="0"
                FontSize="Small"
                SelectedItem ="{Binding Car.Color}"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                SelectedIndexChanged="Picker_SelectedIndexChanged"
                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Title="Select a color">
                <Picker.ItemsSource>
                    <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                        <x:String>Red</x:String>
                        <x:String>Blue</x:String>
                        <x:String>Gray</x:String>                                                        
                    </x:Array>
                </Picker.ItemsSource>
            </Picker>
            <Button
                FontSize="Small"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="2"
                Margin="10"
                Command="{Binding SubmitComboboxCommand}"
                IsEnabled="{Binding IsComboboxComplete}"
                Style="{StaticResource ButtonOutline}"
                Text="Change Color" />
```

In the code-behind, CarPage.cs, I have this:

```
private void Picker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                ViewModel.IsComboboxComplete = (((Picker)sender).SelectedIndex != -1);
            }
```

Fine. Nevermind the IsComboboxComplete flag. This is the problem I have:

In the CarViewModel I have this command:

```
            [RelayCommand]
        private async Task<Task> SubmitCombobox()
        {
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Submit", $"The color of this car is now '{car.Color}' !", "OK");
            return Task<Task>.CompletedTask;
        }
```

But this command does actually nothing, since I have the SelectedItem ="{Binding Car.Color}" line above, which binds the Picker to my car, so the button is useless. I would like to remove the line

```
SelectedItem ="{Binding Car.Color}"
```

and set the color of the car without the binding, on the button call. But my SubmitCombobox() method lies in the CarViewModel, and so in the model I should apply the selected color to the Car object. But how do I get the selected color in the viewmodel ? How do I know which is the SelectedItem of my Picker object if there is no binding ? In the CarViewModel I have no knowledge of the status of my controls as I do in code-behind, in CarPage.cs.

So this is actually more a MVVM problem than a MAUI problem.

Also, I would like to instantly refresh my label, above, to show the new color, but for that I assume I would need a RefreshView, which needs a command, like

```
Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}
```

but again, in that RefreshCommand.... how do I reload the car ?

Thank you for reading this.
Alex.

Comment: if you're using MVVM then you should use binding.  What **specific** problem do you need to solve that the binding is preventing you from doing?

Comment: @Jason, what I wanted to ask is this: how do I allow the user to freely play with the settings of the object (Car) shown on this page without actually saving these settings in my Car object until the user actually clicks on some Commit button ? Because right now the Car object, being bound, is already changed, and so if the user exits this "Details" screen and enters it back again, all his changes are still there, without him ever clicking on some Submit button to make those changes stick.

Comment: make a copy of the Car object and bind to the copy.  When they save, persist the changes from the temp copy to the "real" one

Comment: Also, the 2nd question was - how do I refresh the screen to show the current (changed) values ? The RefreshView needs a RefreshCommand. What should be in that RefreshCommand ? The Car object is already changed (see above), but the bound fields do not update. What should I write in my RefreshCommand code ? Again, Thank you very much - I am trying to learn this MVVM and Maui things.

Comment: @Jason I understand. Will do that. I consider Question 1 now solved, thank you, Jason !

Comment: if you're using data binding the UI and VM should stay sync'd.  Are you implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your VM (or whatever class you are binding to)?

Comment: I am using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm, so my VM inherits from a base class named BaseViewModel which implements ObservableObject 

This ObservableObject inherits, I see, from INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging

Comment: See [ObservableObject / Simple property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observableobject#simple-property). The code snippet shows what each property setter needs to look like. The "SetProperty" is what tells any bound values (e.g. your xaml) that the property has changed. You don't need any "refresh" call - just correctly written property setters. ADVICE: If this still isn't clear to you, Find any Xamarin MVVM tutorial or video that explains this stuff. Maui works the same.